# Add multiple datatable and tabitem.content for each tabitem in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    This is my xmal code for tabcontrol 
    <TabControl  x:Name="tabControl1" Grid.Row="2"  Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding tabs}" SelectionChanged="tabControl1_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvaluation}" TabStripPlacement="Top" >
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Day"  Binding="{Binding [Day]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding [Date]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding [Time]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Lat" Binding="{Binding [Lat]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Long" Binding="{Binding [Long]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Address" Binding="{Binding [Address]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Accuracy" Binding="{Binding [Accuracy]}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding [Type]}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>


And this is my code to create tabs
public void LoadData()
{
    sy.OpenFileDialog op = new sy.OpenFileDialog();
    op.Multiselect = true;

    if (op.ShowDialog() == sy.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        for each (string s in op.FileNames)
        {
            val = s;
            values = s.Split('\\');
            lastItem = values[values.Length - 1];                   
            newTabItem = new TabItem
            {
                Header = lastItem,
            };
            tabControl1.Items.Add(newTabItem);
            ReadJsonFile();                   

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Lat", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Long", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(item.getDay(), item.getDate(), item.getTime(), item.getLat(), item.getLongi(), item.getAddresst(), item.getTYpe());                    
            }
            newTabItem.Content =  dt;

        }
    }
}

public void ReadJsonFile()
{
    string json = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(val))
    {
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var test = JObject.Parse(json);
        JArray items = (JArray)test["locations"];
        int length = items.Count;
        data = new List<Info>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = test["locations"][i]["timestampMs"];
            double dTimeSpan = Convert.ToDouble(d);
            DateTime dtReturn = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(Math.Round(dTimeSpan / 1000d)).ToLocalTime();
            string printDate = dtReturn.DayOfWeek.ToString() + "," + " " + dtReturn.ToShortDateString() + " " + dtReturn.ToShortTimeString();
            day = dtReturn.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            date = dtReturn.ToShortDateString();
            time = dtReturn.ToShortTimeString();
            var e = test["locations"][i]["latitudeE7"];
            var f = test["locations"][i]["longitudeE7"];
            //getLocationByGeoLocation(e.ToString(), f.ToString());                   
            var g = test["locations"][i]["activity"] != null;

            if (g == true)
            {
                JArray items1 = (JArray)test["locations"][i]["activity"];
                int length1 = items1.Count;

                while (j < items1.Count )
                {
                    if(j == 0)
                    { 
                        var h = test["locations"][i]["activity"][j]["activity"][j]["type"];
                        type = h.ToString();
                        j = 1;
                    }
                    else { }
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
        }
        else { }

        Info ddm = new Info(day, date, time, lat, longi, address, type);
        data.Add(ddm);                   
    }
}
return;
```

}

Now I want when creating every new tab create a data table for each tab. for ex. if I create 5 tabs then for each tab new data table and tab item content to be open because I want to apply a filter on all tab but if two tabs are open then I only able to apply filter on last open tab.

This image  show that two tabs are open but when i apply filter first tab cannot filter

[image]

And the on last tab filter is applied
[image]

I don't know how to do this please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused with your posted sample

You are binding tabcontrol itemssource to tabs, but I did not see, where you set tabs property in code.
Next When you are binging itemssource, where is your Itemtemplate?
Next LoadData describes that your are directly adding items to tabControl, instead of adding to tabs property.

Can you please follow simple steps as mentioned below.
1. Fill your tabs property in load data. Note that create tabs property as Observable collection. Also You should not create property as dataset (list of datatable) I would suggest to create simple class with Notify property.
2. Bind tabs property to tabControl itemssource
3. Define Itemtemplate for tabControl
Thats all.

Please reverse your requirement. i.e. first create dataset (i would suggest to create ObservableCollection). bind it to tabControl. so you will get one tabitem per item in tab property.
Next you want to apply filter. its easy. GetSelectedItem and apply your filter. and reset filter for previous item. You can get previous and current selectedItem in SelectoinChange event args.

Hope it will work